# Why does styling a Bootstrap modal with dialogClassName set and using Styled JSX require the global tag?

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, jsx, next.js

I am using Next.js (React) with Bootstrap and styled JSX. I am running into an issue where a custom class in Bootstrap for a modal is only styled with css if the css if global. I declare the custom class using the dialogClassName property on  the Modal. This is my function component (I am using Typescript):

```
const Form: React.FunctionComponent<props> = (props: props) => {
  const [FormVisibility, FormDispatch] = useContext(FormContext);
  return (
      <Modal
        show={props.isVisible}
        onHide={() => {FormDispatch({ type: ActionTypes.CloseForm }) }}
        backdrop="static"
        dialogClassName="custom-modal"
        >
        <Modal.Header closeButton >
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => {FormDispatch({ type: ActionTypes.CloseForm }) }}>
            Close
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
        <style jsx global>{`
      .custom-modal {
        color: blue;
        height: 75vh;
        width: 75vw;
        max-width: none !important;
      }
      `}
      </style>
      </Modal>
  );
}
```

This works just fine. But if I were to change `<style jsx global>` to `<style jsx>` then the styling isn't applied. Am I doing something wrong here or is  there a better way to do this? It seems weird to me that global is needed even though the component has the class declared locally.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience working with Modals is that the modal element is actually extracted out of the DOM tree where your component lives and placed at the top most level right under the body tag.

```
<body>
   // Component where the Modal is declared
   <Form />
   <div>
    // Modal appears here
    // Styles are not applied because Modal is not nested within Form component
   </div>
</body>
```

It is possible that your local style is not applied because of this reason.

Comment: ah, you are right I didn't even notice that was the case. Thanks! Do you think there is a better way to go about styling the modal then?

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong with what you are doing right now. If you are keen to keep using styled JSX then maybe try using the one-off global selector, https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx#one-off-global-selectors. This ensures that only the `custom-modal` class is globally scoped if you want to add other classes within the local scope of that component.

Comment: The one-off global selector sounds like a good way to go about it. I will check it out. Thank you for the feedback!